# Swift compiler unable to resolve correct overload of + operator for arrays in generic function

Tags: swift, generics, operator-overloading

I've had several problems with the plus operator so I decided to investigate and ended up with the following minimal example. When I compile

```
func f<T>(t: T) -> [T]
{
    return [t] + [t]
}
```

everything is fine. The compiler chooses this overload of the plus operator:

```
public func +<RRC1 : RangeReplaceableCollection, RRC2 : RangeReplaceableCollection
    where RRC1.Iterator.Element == RRC2.Iterator.Element>
    (lhs: RRC1, rhs: RRC2) -> RRC1
```

However, when I add another `+` to the game, I get this:

```
func f<T>(t: T) -> [T]
{
    return [t] + [t] + [t]
}

main.swift:30:9: error: cannot convert value of type '[T]' to expected argument type '[_]' (aka 'Array<_>')
    return [t] + [t] + [t]
           ^~~
               as! [_]
```

I found several ways to make this work, like for instance `return ([t] as [T]) + [t] + [t]`, or this:

```
func f<T>(t: T) -> [T]
{
    let t1 = [t]
    return t1 + [t] + [t]
}
```

(which is probably essentially the same) but I wonder what the actual problem is. Is this is a bug in the compiler
or what am I not understanding here? And what is the `[_]` in the error message trying to tell me?

I've also looked at the ASTs but, having only shallow Compilers 101 knowledge, this just seems to confirm my hunch that the compiler is unable
to find the correct version of the plus operator.

I am using Xcode 8.2.1 (8C1002) with the included

```
$ swift --version
Apple Swift version 3.0.2 (swiftlang-800.0.63 clang-800.0.42.1)
Target: x86_64-apple-macosx10.9
```

**Update**

I forgot that adding parentheses to the statement (either `([t] + [t]) + [t]` or `[t] + ([t] + [t])`) doesn't compile either, while `return (+)([t], [t]) + [t]` does.

Comment: Looks like another case ([similar problem here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42250149/2976878)) of the type-checker just being stretched too far when chaining together multiple binary operators, as it significantly increases the complexity of overload resolution (especially given you're using array literals as the operands). In any case, feel free to [file a bug](https://bugs.swift.org).

Comment: @Hamish: What's special about array literals? That there are several overloads of `+` for various protocols they can be interpreted as?

Comment: Array literals can be interpreted as any concrete type that conforms to `ExpressibleByArrayLiteral`, which complicates the overload resolution further (although they will default to `Array` if they cannot be inferred to be a specific concrete type).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I did what Hamish suggested and filed [SR-4304](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-4304). According to Jordan Rose this is still broken in master. I will update this answer when there is any news on the bug.